# Is the screen of the Macbook Pro with M1 chip quite fragile?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, apple-silicon

I was thinking about buying the newest Macbook Pro with 13" screen. But when I search online for reviews, some people say the screen of the Macbook Pro is quite fragile.

Is this still an issue now?

https://www.pcmag.com/news/apple-facing-m1-macbook-cracked-screen-class-action-lawsuit

https://www.reddit.com/r/macbook/comments/psau8u/m1_screen_cracked_on_its_own/

41 pages of threads about macbook air's screen: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252794122?page=41

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Apple sells something like 20 million laptops a year. Even if you've got 100 people having experienced cracked displays (where some of them got them replaced for free by Apple) - that's still a vanishingly small number compared to how many actually bought laptops.

I personally wouldn't have any problems at all buying a MacBook Pro with an M1 chip.

Answer (score 1):

There has been no follow-up news about the class-action suit since it was announced 6 months ago.

Assuming that there were defects in the manufacturing process that lead to screens "spontaneously cracking" in the 13-inch M1 laptops (which were released in 2020), the chances are high that the factory would have improved their quality controls, particularly now that demand has eased off.